# How format content of EditText in afterTextChanged?

Tags: android

```
txt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {

                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    String value = txt1.getText().toString();
                    txt1.setText(String.valueOf(Utilities
                            .roundOneDecimals(Double.parseDouble(value))));
              }
        });
```

If set text agian in [afterTextChanged] , program will call event again.

How format content of EditText in afterTextChanged?

Comment: A boolean flag fixes the recursion :)

Comment: @BojanKseneman Indeed indeed

Answer (score 1):

Like @Bojan Kseneman suggestion, a `boolean` flag solve the problem.

```
boolean enableChangeListener = true;

txt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {

                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if(enableChangeListener){
                        enableChangeListener = false;
                        String value = txt1.getText().toString();
                        txt1.setText(String.valueOf(Utilities
                            .roundOneDecimals(Double.parseDouble(value))));
                    }

              }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this in my projects, it works as it should. Use it like this `editText.addTextChangesLisener(new MyTextWatcher(editText));`

However as I mentioned in my comment, a simple boolean fflag will fix your problem.

```
    public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;

        public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
            editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
            if (editText == null) return;
            String s = editable.toString();
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            // Do your formatting here     
            editText.setText(String.valueOf(Utilities
                        .roundOneDecimals(Double.parseDouble(s))));editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString.length());
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Odds are this code works without it and does not leak, I did not test it. I just weakreferenced it, just to be sure it's not leaking. Also views hold the reference to the context, which happens to be an activity, if you leak a view, you leak your activity... this is a bigger problem than you may think :)